# Nuances between "неужели" and "разве" in this specific context

Tags: словоупотребление

I just wrote in an IM:

> Вот бы и мне туда! **Неужели** когда-нибудь простые люди тоже смогут летать на Луну?

Here I'm entertaining the possibility of space travel in a rather hopeful tone: "I wonder if the day will come when we ...". But then, I wondered how the use of "разве" would have compared. Does "разве", on the other hand, impart a rather negative, sceptical flavour to my remark: "Will the day ever come when we ..."?

> {vs}: Вот бы и мне туда! Но серьезно, **разве** когда-нибудь простые люди тоже смогут летать на Луну?

[ a relevant [post](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12312/what-is-the-difference-between-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5-and-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) ]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right and your remark shows deep understanding of these constructs.

*Неужели* implies you've accepted the fact you were skeptical of but still express your surprise, *разве* means you have not accepted it yet and are looking for additional confirmation.

> — Он придёт с женой. — Неужели он женился? // "He will come with his wife". "He's married? I'm surprised!"
>
> — Он придёт с женой. — Разве он женился? // "He will come with his wife". "I was not aware he was married, is he?"

*Неужели* is more often than not a rhetorical question, *разве* more often than not requires an actual answer.

Comment: Upping this, the subtle difference is there, but frankly, there's no difference in *real use* of these two.

Comment: I'd say there is. "Разве" is less generic and used less often, it is more pessimistic.

Comment: I wonder if "**Мне вот интересно, можно ли когда-нибудь ...**" is close in meaning to "неужели" in my remark, albeit somewhat more enthusiastically hopeful about the prospect.

Comment: @Alone-zee: this is a neutral question ("I wonder if...") and does not convey the element of surprise. Both *неужели* and *разве* assume you did not really believe in Moon flights before.

Comment: Use "мне вот интересно" as you would when "speaking of which; if you mention that" would be implied.

Comment: @Alone-zee that phrase lacks a verb (well, maybe it was to be there in the omitted part, just that it is not there yet. I perceive it, when expeanded, to be kind of "Мне вот интересно, можно ли когда-нибудь [по]лететь на Луну" ), so sounds a bit weird. I feel more idiomatic would be "Интересно, можно ли БУДЕТ когда-нибудь ..."  or "Интересно, УДАСТСЯ ли когда-нибудь ..." or "Интересно, СМОЖЕМ ли МЫ когда-нибудь ..." instead. The two latter variants additionally express your attitude to the prospect: you explicitly hope for that with to eventually be granted.

Comment: How do "неужто" and "нешто" compare with "неужели"?

Comment: @alonezee: those are vulgarisms and _нешто_ has additional meaning of "if only", but otherwise they mean the same